# Notmuch - configure preferences for address completion

Tags: completion, notmuch

When hitting TAB in notmuch to complete email addresses, I often get a long(ish) list of possible completions, forcing me to cycle through it looking for the correct one.

Is there a way to order the possible completions, so that I get the most relevant first?  Relevant can here be defined as the most recently used, the most common from-address, or selected from a list of specific domain priorities.

Comment: I would add a related question: if you use the internal address completion, how do you edit that database to change the order of addresses for someone who has 2 or more addresses?